# Rotate card in Angular function

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I would like when the customer clicked on the input "Código de Segurança * *" the card would call the class that rotates it to the back "black"

```
<div class="col-lg-3">
<label for="codSeg">Código de Segurança<span class="text-danger"> *</span></label>
<input maxlength="4"  name="cvv" #cvvCard formControlName="digiCVV" id="codSeg" 
class="form-control w-50" type="text" [ngClass]="{'back  flip': (!cvvCard.value)}" 
(click)="changeCVV()" >
</div>
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OAUH.png)

Comment: Which card!? Please share more information. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create an example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: If you put a space in `'back  flip'`, I suspect the element will get two classes, `back` and `flip`. What do those do anyway?

Comment: .back {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
.flip {
    transition: 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;
  }